# Питон 3.7 при установке пакета с помощью pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl

Помогите исправить ошибку, как установить модуль OpenSSl

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\Linux>cd C:\Users\Linux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scrip
ts

C:\Users\Linux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install pya
udio
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in
 Python is not available.
Collecting pyaudio
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pyaudio/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pyaudio/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pyaudio/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pyaudio/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pyaudio/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyaudio/: There was a problem conf
irming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyaudio/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect t
o HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyaudio (from versions
: )
No matching distribution found for pyaudio
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in
 Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming
 the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retrie
s exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS UR
```

Comment: Какой дистрибутив Python используете?

Comment: Какая версия Windows?

Comment: Переустановите Python

Comment: Виндовс 7, питон 3,7 все решил просто скачал питон 3.5 там не нужен SSl